# Start time and End time Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Html for selecting from time and to time.

Select Date Tab

```
<div class="elementbox">
                <label class="form-label">Select Date</label>
                <div class="controls">
                 <div class="half-container"><div class="left"><span>From</span> <div class="icongroup"><input type="text" id="from" name="from"/><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div></div></div>
                 <div class="half-container"><div class="left"><span class="text-center">To</span> <div class="icongroup"><input type="text" id="to" name="to"/> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div> </div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Select time tab

```
<div class="elementbox">
                <label class="form-label">Select Time</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="half-container"><div class="left"><span>From</span> <div class="icongroup"><input type="text" id="from_t" name="from_t"/> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div></div></div>
                    <div class="half-container"><div class="left"><span  class="text-center">To</span> <div class="icongroup"><input type="text" id="to_t" name="to_t"/> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to show that if date is today then Start time is selected of 03:00 AM then to time should be greater than 03:00 AM or else it should allow to select the time instead of disabling the time.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my jquery code:
     From date and to date

```
    $("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect:function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('error')){
          $(this).trigger('keyup')
        }
    },
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});

$("#to").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect:function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('error')){
          $(this).trigger('keyup')
        }
    },
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

From time and To time

```
$('#from_t').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
$('#to_t').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
```

I am using jquery timepicker js to achieve this.

Comment: which format are you using 12h or 24h

Comment: 12h AM/PM format

Comment: I think using the 24H format will be the best way in order to archive what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question, I can change it if solution is good then

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minTime: '11:00'` inside `timepicker` parameters

Referrence: [DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minTime)